# number of connection required for parameterized report in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I face one interview question on SSRS which I don't know the answer.

How many connections/datasets required for parameterized report in SSRS

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a strange interview question and implies you've never used SSRS - but nevertheless, to answer your question the minimum is 1 connection to a server, 1 dataset and 1 parameter. I suggest you create a report and use this as a [starting point](https://www.sqlshack.com/create-sql-server-reporting-services-ssrs-report/) to increase your understanding.